# using `fsolve` to solve m equations with n unknowns where n<m

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

Imagine I have two equations with one unknown and I want to use `fsolve` to solve it:

```
0 = 0.5*x[0]**2-2
0 = 2-x
```

Clearly the answer is `x=2`. I have tried this

```
import numpy as np; from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def f(x):
    r  = np.zeros(2)
    r[0] =  0.5*x[0]**2-2
    r[1] = 2-x[0]

    return r

fsolve(f,[0.5])
```

The error message is **"The array returned by a function changed size between calls"**

I can't see what is going wrong here. How do I solve this problem?

In general, How do I solve equations where the number of variables is less than the number of equations.

Here is the full message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-e4f77791f3f6>", line 12, in <module>
    fsolve(f,[0.5])

  File "... anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 148, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

  File ".... /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 227, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)

ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of overdetermined system (the number of equations is greater than the  number of variables)you need to use, for example, least squares approach. In such cases, there are usually no solution in traditional sense. And we need to define, what should we treat as a solution of the system.

Let you have a system of two equations with one scalar variable:

f(x) = 0
g(x) = 0

This system  usually inconsistent and have no solution in traditional sense.

Lets add some values eps1 and eps2 to the right part of the system:

f(x) = 0 + eps1
g(x) = 0 + eps2

eps1 and eps2 are some values;

Now, lets find such `x` when `eps1^2 + eps2^2` is rises its minimum value; that will be a solution  of the system 
in least squares sense.

To get such solution using scipy you can use [least_square](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) function.

Lets look at the following piece of code, that solves your system of equations:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, least_squares
def f(x):
    r  = np.zeros(2)
    r[0] =  0.5*x**2-2
    r[1] = 2-x

    return r

least_squares(f, [0.0])
```

Result:

```
active_mask: array([0.])
        cost: 5.175333019854869e-20
         fun: array([ 2.87759150e-10, -1.43879575e-10])
        grad: array([7.19397879e-10])
         jac: array([[ 2.00000001],
       [-1.        ]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 6
        njev: 6
  optimality: 7.193978788924559e-10
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([2.])
```